# cells not being made/displayed

Tags: javascript

im relatively new to coding and i am having an issue with my code, and it isnt a syntax error.
using visual studio code, the goLive extension, and a js file connected to an html file.

the link to the picture is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGjLW.png)
, and although it looks cut off, there is nothing below it

sorry if the code is a bit messy, im not good by any means. it doesnt make the grid though, and i dont know why?

i realized i had an issue with the className function, so i changed it from:

tile.className(cell-white/black);

**to**

tile.className = "cell-white/black";

that took away the error i got, but it still didnt work.

Comment: Take a look again at [ask]. Code in questions should be formatted text, not pictures. People can't run the code from a picture

Comment: Also would be nice to see what your css looks like.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick working solution:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #board {
        display: table;
      }
      .row {
        display: table-row;
        height: 50px;
      }
      .cell-black {
        display: table-cell;
        background-color: black;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
      }
      .cell-white {
        display: table-cell;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        const columns = 8;
        const rows = 8;
        generateBoard(columns, rows);
      }
      
      function generateBoard(cols, rows) {
        const board = document.getElementById('board');
        for(let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
          const row = document.createElement('div');
          row.className = 'row';
          for(let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            const cell = document.createElement('div');
            if (r % 2 === 0){
              cell.className = c % 2 === 0 ? 'cell-black' : 'cell-white';
            }
            else {
              cell.className = c % 2 === 0 ? 'cell-white' : 'cell-black';
            }
            row.append(cell)
          }
          board.append(row);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="board"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

To test locally just save this code as `index.html` somewhere on your computer and open with Chrome or Firefox, or maybe you can run it using VS Code and goLive extension.
Also I would suggest that you rename the question to be something like drawing chessboard-like grid using javascript, css and html.